# jQuery Mobile Phonegap iOS: Header flickers when I pull up keyboard

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova

Title pretty much sums it up. I have a fixed persistent header via:

```
<div data-role="header"  data-id="headerbar" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">

            <h1>Title!</h1>  
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn-right">Login</a> 
        </div>
```

And then another header via:

```
<div data-role="header"  data-theme="c">
        <h6>1. Type a name </h6> 
        <input type="search" name="name" id="basic" value=""></input>
    </div>
```

When I click on the text input in the xcode simulator (and on my actual iphone), the first header turns solid white then flicks back to the proper header.

Ideas?

My screen looks like this:[image: Sim Screen]

Comment: u intend to use two headers in same page?

Comment: Can u paste the image of what ur screen is like?

Comment: @JoshDG Did you make any progress with this? Having a similar problem where a search input in a fixed header makes the header flicker whenever the keyboard appears/disappears. It's not a deal breaker, but it sure is annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `<label>` instead of `<header>`

```
<label for="search-basic">Select Name:</label>
<input type="search" name="search" id="searc-basic" value="" data-mini="true" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Vu4r/3/

**EDIT:** Its the property of the `data-position="fixed"` attribute of jQuery Mobile. what it does is It vanishes the toolbars when scrolling of the screen does.Like wise if you tap on screen it vanishes & if you tap again it shows up the toolbars. So thats why your header is vanished if u clicked for the 1st time again it pops up back when you click again. Please remove that attrib if its not in use. Hope it helps.

Comment: that does help my formatting, but the other header (the top one) still flickers.

Comment: see my **EDIT** Please. You confused me by saying "turns solid white" & terming it as "flickering effect".

Comment: Hmmmmn. Well that did fix the problem so I accepted the answer, but I do want it to be a fixed header... i dont want it to move when I scroll..can I do that? Thanks for your help btw :)

Comment: well, go just with default `data-role="header"` & `data-role="footer"` In that case the header & footer are shown right at top. & footer at bottom of the page content(text) but not at bottom of screen. I dont know if I am confusing you. As I would say it always depends on your page requirements (the length of txt u put in a page). You need to play a lil bit on that to get good grasp of things.  :)

Comment: Yeah I may not understand you..although I DEFINITELY have to play more to get a grasp... I mean..I'm using it as an app so I really don't want the header to scroll with the page..which it will do if I dont make it fixed...is there a way to make it NOT vanish the fixed bars when the screen is tapped or scrolled?

Comment: as far as I know there is no default way, you may do with your own custom functions though. Simply, What I intend to say in previous comment is if you have default footer it will always be shown right after you text, may not be at the bottom of the page it might be in center of page or somewhere else where the text ends, but header stays at top of page. Put some 100 lines of text & play with those toolbar attribs, not a big task takes few mins though.

Answer (score 2):

As @uDaY told, removing data-position="fixed", helped me get rid of issues mentioned @uDay's EDIT. @JoshDG In div data-role="header" you can try style="position:fixed" and realign if you see any change in alignment, to make your header fixed. :) Thank you for your solutions and questions.

Comment: For me, when I remove the data-position and put only the style, the alignment is lost. So, I left the data-position and put the style:

<div id="evento_header" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" style="position:fixed">...</div>

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a major bug of jQuery Mobile. There are many issue is opening about this and they are set the milestone at next release (at least 1.3.1). https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5532